# Crear un RecyclerView con CursorAdapter para base de datos con múltiples tablas

Tags: android

En mi aplicación Android estoy intentando introducir una base de datos de 18 tablas y aunque estoy terminando el proceso para introducir la BD en mi app, ya he empezado a mirar como visualizar los datos de una tabla en un `RecyclerView` y para mi sorpresa he descubierto que tengo que utilizar un `RecyclerView` con un `CursorAdapter` personalizado.

Se más o menos que es un cursor, pero no encuentro como poder crear un `CursorAdapter` personalizado para enviar la información de la tabla de la BD al  `RecyclerView`.

He estado buscando información por Internet y no encuentro nada que detalle como crearlo. Solo he encontrado librerías que han creado otros programadores, pero no quisiera meter librerías externas si se puede hacer sin ellas.

¿Alguien sabría decirme como crearlo y así poder entenderlo?

No creo que se necesite más información para aportar una respuesta, pero si no es así, escribidme un comentario.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: He agregado una respuesta Vicky, pero tengo curiosidad que libreria has encontrado para esto, solo para revisarla, saludos.

Comment: Si claro, en [este enlace](http://androidessence.com/recyclerview-cursoradapter-library/) encontré una de las librerías. También encontré una dedicada al `SimpleCursorAdapter`, pero no encuentro el enlace en mi historial web. Como no me servia, no guarde el link. También había dos paginas más que definían su código como librerías, pero me acabo de dar cuenta de que no lo eran ya que no hay una linea de `compile` para el gradle. Siento ese error. @Elenasys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo evito también usar librerías, de hecho son pocas las que uso. En un proyecto tengo una implementacion similar y este `CustomAdapter` es el que uso:

`CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.java`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

/**
 * Created by skyfishjy.
 */

public abstract class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {

    private Context mContext;

    private Cursor mCursor;

    private boolean mDataValid;

    private int mRowIdColumn;

    private DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver;

    public CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = cursor;
        mDataValid = cursor != null;
        mRowIdColumn = mDataValid ? mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id") : -1;
        mDataSetObserver = new NotifyingDataSetObserver();
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
    }

    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return mCursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return mCursor.getLong(mRowIdColumn);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super.setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, Cursor cursor);

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int position) {
        if (!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
        }
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
        }
        onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, mCursor);
    }

    /**
     * Change the underlying cursor to a new cursor. If there is an existing cursor it will be
     * closed.
     */
    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
        if (old != null) {
            old.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap in a new Cursor, returning the old Cursor.  Unlike
     * {@link #changeCursor(Cursor)}, the returned old Cursor is <em>not</em>
     * closed.
     */
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        if (newCursor == mCursor) {
            return null;
        }
        final Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
        if (oldCursor != null && mDataSetObserver != null) {
            oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
        mCursor = newCursor;
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mDataSetObserver != null) {
                mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }
            mRowIdColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            mRowIdColumn = -1;
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
        }
        return oldCursor;
    }

    private class NotifyingDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            super.onInvalidated();
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
        }
    }
}
```

`MyListCursorAdapter.java`:

```
Raw  MyListCursorAdapter.java
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by skyfishjy on 10/31/14.
 */
public class MyListCursorAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<MyListCursorAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    public MyListCursorAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor){
       super(context,cursor);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
        MyListItem myListItem = MyListItem.fromCursor(cursor);
        viewHolder.mTextView.setText(myListItem.getName());
    }
}
```

Tu adapter tiene que extender de [CustomRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59), este es el link del código:

https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59

Comment: Hola @Elenasys , tengo una pequeña duda sobre el código. En el archivo `CursorRecyclerViewAdapter` existe una clase llamada `NotifyingDataSetObserver`. No acabo de entender muy bien para que sirve esta clase, ¿podrías dejar una breve explicación, sobre para que funciona? Si tengo alguna otra duda, te lo haré saber y cuando funcione también. Gracias. :)

Comment: Hola @VickyVicent revisa en en método y veras que tiene  notifyDataSetChanged() en realidad actualiza los datos dentro del adapter.