# ¿SQLite de Android no admite ids auto incrementales que no se llamen "_id"?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Estoy realizando una implementación de una base de datos en mi aplicación Android y me a llamado la atención en que todos los tutoriales que he visto, siempre llaman al id de las tablas `_id` o que llaman a una interfaz llamada [BaseColumns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html?hl=es) que aporta el nombre en string `_id`.

Yo no estoy utilizando el nombre `_id` para todos los id de las tablas de mi base de datos. Un ejemplo de un id de mi BD seria `idPedidos` porque mi tabla se llama `Pedidos`, además la mayoría son `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

**Mi pregunta es si realmente estoy trabajando en vano por no poner el nombre `_id` al id de mis tablas y si es así, ¿por qué sucede esto si solo es un nombre string?**

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), si admite ids auto-incrementales que no se llamen “_id”, te comento que en algunos proyectos también tengo una columna definida como [AUTOINCREMENT](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) que no es _id y en ocasiones la uso como referencia.

La razón principal para tener el campo _id es que en algunos proyectos **regularmente usamos cursores para acceder a los datos en una BD Sqlite**,  me parece que tu preguntabas acerca de un Custom CursorAdapter, por lo tanto la importancia de la columna _id es:

> [CursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html): El cursor debe incluir una columna denominada "_id" o esta clase no
>   funcionará. Además, el uso de MergeCursor con esta clase no funcionará
>   si los cursores fusionadas tienen superposición de valores en sus
>   columnas "_id".

si no tienes definida la columna _id, obtendrías el mensaje:

> The Cursor must include a column named _id or this class will not
>   work.

Si vas a crear un Cursor para acceder a los datos se debe usar `_id`

```
Cursor c = db.query("....");
```

Comment: Vaya... Gracias @Elenasys , realmente esta pregunta fue causada por la contestación que me diste en [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/11881/4684), pero como era larga de explicar en un comentario, la puse como pregunta. De todas formas, ¿existe alguna alternativa al `Cursor` con la que pueda utilizar el id que me de la gana? Yo en java con hibernate utilizaba `DefaultListModel` que es como el `Cursor`, pero no existe en Android. Como alternativa chapucera había pensado usar `ArrayLists`, pero antes de aplicar, preguntar.