# Implementar "onClickListener" en RecyclerView funcionando con Cursor

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-intent

Hace unos días formule una pregunta en la que pedía ayuda y orientaciones sobre como crear un `RecyclerView` con un `CursorAdapter` para poder crear una lista donde los datos del `RecyclerView` eran extraídos de la BD (en SQLite) interna de la propia app. [Aquí el enlace de la pregunta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11881/crear-un-recyclerview-con-cursoradapter-para-base-de-datos-con-m%C3%BAltiples-tablas)

Hoy, quería implementar el método `onClickListener` para que, cuando el usuario pulsase encima de un ítem de la lista, se abriera una nueva `Activity` donde aparecieran todos los datos de ese ítem.

Por lógica y por varios ejemplos fallidos de Internet, se que tengo que implementar el `onClickListener` dentro del adaptador del `RecyclerView` y, a partir de ahí, coger el dato `_id` del ítem que se a seleccionado, consultar los datos de ese registro y pasarlo a la nueva `Activity` por un `Intent`, pero no consigo obtener este `_id` del ítem.

**¿Cómo hago para conseguir el `_id` del ítem seleccionado? ¿Me estoy olvidando de algo? ¿Lo estoy haciendo mal? ¿El método `onClickListener` no se implementa en el `RecyclerAdapter` o si? ¿Realmente se puede implementar `onClickListener` o se tiene que utilizar `OnItemTouchListener` que si esta en el `RecyclerView` según la [documentación de Google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html)?**

Este es el código del adaptador del `RecyclerView` que extiende de `CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<ListsAdapter.ViewHolder>`:

```
public class ListsAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<ListsAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    Cursor c;
    Context context;
    Cursor cursor;

    //Constructor
    public ListsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
        this.context = context;
        this.cursor = cursor;
        c = cursor;
    }

    // Para enlazar el diseño del ítem a la lista
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.design_item_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView, context);
    }

    // Para declarar las variables del layout seleccionado y poder llenarlas después
    // Aquí he implementado el "OnClickListener"
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView title, delivery, aux;
        Context context;
        Cursor cursor;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            this.context = context;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_item);
            delivery = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delivery);
            aux = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        }

        // Aquí es donde se supone tengo que coger el _id del registro del cursor, pero no se como. También tengo que abrir la nueva activity, pasandole los datos del registro del cursor por un un intent.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Aquí necesito de alguna forma coger el _id y hacer 
            // aparecer la nueva activity

            ArrayList<String> data = selectData();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailsHomeworkActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("datos", data);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        // Desde aquí queria obtener los datos del cursor, pero al no saber
        // como coger el _id no puedo obtener esos datos.
        // Se supone que tendría que pasar como dato sobrecargado el _id.
        private ArrayList<String> selectData(){
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            data.add(cursor.getString(0));// _ID - Integer
            data.add(cursor.getString(1));// Nombre del deber
            data.add(cursor.getString(2));// Nombre del tipo de deber
            data.add(cursor.getString(3));// tieneNota - Booleano
            data.add(cursor.getString(4));// Descripcion
            data.add(cursor.getString(5));// Fecha entrega
            data.add(cursor.getString(6));// Hora de entrega
            data.add(cursor.getString(7));// Ubicacion
            data.add(cursor.getString(8));// Grado de tipo de prioridad
            data.add(cursor.getString(9));// Nombre de la asignatura
            data.add(cursor.getString(10));// Calificación
            data.add(cursor.getString(11));// Terminado - Booleano

            return data;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ListsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {

        holder.title.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        holder.delivery.setText(cursor.getString(9));
        if (cursor.getString(5).equals("null")) {
            holder.aux.setText("");
        } else {
            holder.aux.setText(cursor.getString(5));
        }
            holder.cursor = cursor;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (c != null) {
            return c.getCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar o que alguien haya creado en su proyecto algo parecido y pueda contestarme y explicarme las preguntas que he formulado.

Gracias de antemano a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como yo he puesto en mi código, se puede implementar un `onClickListener` sin ningún problema.

El único problema que tenia, era que necesitaba coger el registro de la BD correspondiente a al ítem seleccionado que estaba guardado en un Cursor y he conseguido una respuesta.

Esta a sido la solución:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Cojo la posición del ítem del ArrayList
        int position = this.getAdapterPosition();
        // Le paso la posición al método "selectData()"
        ArrayList<String> data = selectData(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ItemDetailsHomeworkActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("datos", data);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private ArrayList<String> selectData(int position){
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        switch (tab) {
            case "deber-unfinished":
                // Muevo el cursor a la posición y empiezo a guardar datos
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                data.add(cursor.getString(0));// _ID - Integer
                data.add(cursor.getString(1));// Nombre del deber
                data.add(cursor.getString(2));// Nombre del tipo de deber
                data.add(cursor.getString(3));// tieneNota - Booleano
                data.add(cursor.getString(4));// Descripcion
                data.add(cursor.getString(5));// Fecha entrega
                data.add(cursor.getString(6));// Hora de entrega
                data.add(cursor.getString(7));// Ubicacion
                data.add(cursor.getString(8));// Grado de tipo de prioridad
                data.add(cursor.getString(9));// Nombre de la asignatura
                data.add(cursor.getString(10));// Calificación
                data.add(cursor.getString(11));// Terminado - Booleano
                break;
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Así cojo los datos en la `Activity` que recoje el `Intent`*:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {//ver si contiene datos
        data = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("datos");

        title.setText(data.get(1));
        type.setText(data.get(2));
        priority.setText(data.get(8));
        aux = data.get(5) + " - " + data.get(6);
        delivery.setText(aux);
        description.setText(data.get(4));
        location.setText(data.get(7));
        subject.setText(data.get(9));
        aux = data.get(3);
        System.out.println("tieneNota es: " + aux);
        mark.setText(data.get(10));
    }
```

Donde yo me había confundido era en que necesitaba el `_id` del registro para poder acceder a el, pero no, porque si la `SELECT` que me saca los registros para poder rellenar la lista tiene 3 registros, en la lista tendrá 3 registros y no más, por eso si obtengo la posición del ítem seleccionado tendré la del registro, tan solo hace falta moverse a través del cursos y listo.

Perdonad las molestias por la pregunta, voy a contrarreloj con esta app y estoy de los nervios. Al final era una tontería, pero no quisiera dejar la pregunta para la gente que quiere implementar esto mismo o crear un `onClickListener` en su `RecyclerView`. Así enriquecemos esta comunidad.

*** También había tenido un pequeño problema al tener que pasar un `ArrayList` a través de un `Intent`, pero gracias a [x4mp73r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13577/4684) lo solucioné.**

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Si! cuando tienes un adapter y usas RecyclerView para obtener la posición regulamente se usa el método getAdapterPosition(), con esto tienes la referencia de que elemento en tu lista de objetos o cursor no tuve tiempo de contestar pero ya lo resolviste tu misma =)