# ¿Cómo pasar un ArrayList por un Intent hacia otra Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

Necesito pasar un `ArrayList` por un `Intent` a otra `Activity` y según he leído por Internet, necesito que los objetos del `ArrayList` sean `Parcelable`, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer esto.

**¿Alguien me puede explicar como pasar un `ArrayList` por un `Intent`?**

He probado utilizando `putExtra` y `putParcelableArrayListExtra`, pero sigo con lo mismo. Este es mi `Intent` de salida:

```
ArrayList<String> data = selectData(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("datos", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

También es necesario decir que no puedo utilizar otra cosa que no sea un `ArrayList` porque el numero de datos que voy a pasar, no tendrán nunca el mismo nombre y serán siempre X datos.

Si existiera otra forma, también me serviría como respuesta.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Existen dos formas de realizar el envio de un ArrayList por medio de un Intent :

Por medio de [**putExtra(String name, Serializable value)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable))

```
ArrayList<String> milista = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("miLista", milista);
startActivity(intent);
```

De esta forma se recibe en SegundaActivity.java :

```
ArrayList<String> lista = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miLista");
```

---

También se realiza usando el método [**putStringArrayListExtra (String name, ArrayList value)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) , donde implícitamente defines que el tipo de dato a enviar es un ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> milista = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SegundaActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("miLista", milista);
startActivity(intent);
```

De esta forma se recibe en SegundaActivity.java :

```
ArrayList<String> lista = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("miLista");
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta pasarlo por medio de `putExtra` de esta manera:

```
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
Intent i = new Intent(this,tuOtraActivity.class);
i.putExtra("miLista", lista);
```

tuOtraActivity:

```
ArrayList<String> lista = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miLista");
```

Comment: Me va perfecto, es una alegría saber que existe algo mas fácil. Uff.. Había probado solo con `.getExtras` y nada. Gracias, estaba apurada.