# Pasar información de un fragment a un activity con un arrayList

Tags: android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

Buen día!
Eh estado investigando acerca de como pasar un arrayList de un Fragment a un Activity, he hecho algunas que otras cosillas para poder lograrlo pero no funciona, el caso es que estoy usando un RecyclerView, al cual contiene un Adapter,  este al pulsar la información se pase al activity.

Adjunto el codigo del Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

   holder.Nombre.setText(items.get(position).getNom_Product());
   holder.Tipo.setText(items.get(position).getTipo());
   holder.Precio.setText(items.get(position).getPrecio());
   holder.Imagen.setImageResource(items.get(position).getImg_Product());

   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), Producto.class);
           intent.putExtra("items1", items);
           holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
       }
   });
```

Aquí agregue la función del onClickListener y según esa parte funciona pero la otra parte a donde mando la información del ArrayList para el Activity.

Adjunto parte del Activity

```
 private void initViews() {
    Imagen1 = findViewById(R.id.imgproduct1);
    NombreProducto = findViewById(R.id.TituloProd);
    NombreTipo = findViewById(R.id.Tipoproduct1);
    NombrePrecio = findViewById(R.id.PrecioPro);

}

private void initValues(){

items = (ArrayList<Players>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("items1");

Log.e("Aquí pasa ", String.valueOf(items));

    NombreProducto.setText(items.getNom_Product());

}
```

En el Log, contiene información pero al momento de agregarlo no encuentra lo que es del items.getNom_Product.

Comment: Si `items` es un `ArrayList` de objetos `Players`, obviamente no tiene el método `getNom_Product`. La clase `ArrayList` no tiene ese método. Tal vez lo tendrán los objetos de la clase `Players`.

Comment: Buenas, puedes probar con: `ArrayList<Players> items = FragmentActivity.arraylist;` dejame saber si te funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Agregando una cosa a la respuesta de @SuperG280, podrias acceder al item de tu lista por su posicion algo asi:

```
private void initValues(){ 
    items = (ArrayList<Players>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("items1");
    Log.e("Aquí pasa ", String.valueOf(items));
    
    //"x" es la posicion del item del que deseas imprimir su nombre de producto
    NombreProducto.setText(items.get(x).getNom_Product());
}
```

Espero te sirva :)

Answer (score 0):

Si items es un `ArrayList` es muy importante usar putParcelableArrayList():

```
Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), Producto.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayList("items1", items);
```

Y tú objeto Players debe implementar la clase `Parcelable` :

```
public class Players implements Parcelable{
```

Para recibir el ArrayList en tu Activity es importante realizarlo en onCreate() :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<Players> ListaObjetos = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("items1");
```

Te sugiero revisar :

[¿Cómo pasar un ArrayList por un Intent hacia otra Activity?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13577/c%C3%B3mo-pasar-un-arraylist-por-un-intent-hacia-otra-activity)

En el caso de enviar un ArrayList de objetos:

[Cómo puedo pasar una lista de objetos de una activity a otra?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19912/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-pasar-una-lista-de-objetos-de-una-activity-a-otra)