# Como llenar recyclerview con cursor

Tags: android

Hola a todos tengo implementado un sqlite, me devuelve la lista completa en un curso, antes lo llenaba en un listview, pero ahora quiero llenarla en un recycler view.

No se por donde empezar, saber si el cursor que tengo me sirve para llenar el recycler.

**ACTULIZACION**

Esta es mi clase que se extiende de un CursorAdapter

```
public class ClientesCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public ClientesCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cliente, viewGroup, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView nombrecliente = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_cliente_nombre);
        TextView nombrelocal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_nombre_negocio);
        ImageView btn_next= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_next_cliente);
        View mView =(View) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator_status);
        String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cnombre));
        String negocio = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Ccodigo));
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cid));
        nombrecliente.setText(nombre + "id:"+id);
        nombrelocal.setText(negocio);
        mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("in view", "onClick");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Funciona muy bien con listview, pero no se porque no funciona el OnSetItemClickListerner y quiero hacerlo con recyclerview.
Entiendo que debo crear otro adaptador para el recycler, pero no se como hacerlo.

Esta es mi clase cliente

```
public class cliente {
    private String cMAId;
    private String cMACODIGO;
    private String cMANOMBRE;
    private String cMADIRECCION;
    private String cMACIUDAD;
    private String cMATIPO;
    private String cMACANAL;
    private String cMALATITUD;
    private String cMALONGITUD;

    public cliente(String cMACODIGO, String cMANOMBRE, String cMADIRECCION, String cMACIUDAD, String cMATIPO, String cMACANAL, String cMALATITUD, String cMALONGITUD) {
        this.cMAId= null;
        this.cMACODIGO = cMACODIGO;
        this.cMANOMBRE = cMANOMBRE;
        this.cMADIRECCION = cMADIRECCION;
        this.cMACIUDAD = cMACIUDAD;
        this.cMATIPO = cMATIPO;
        this.cMACANAL = cMACANAL;
        this.cMALATITUD = cMALATITUD;
        this.cMALONGITUD = cMALONGITUD;
    }
    public ContentValues toContentValues(){
        ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
        values.put(contracts.clienterEntry.Cid,cMAId);
        values.put(contracts.clienterEntry.Ccodigo,cMACODIGO);
        values.put(contracts.clienterEntry.Cnombre,cMANOMBRE);
        values.put(contracts.clienterEntry.Cdireccion,cMADIRECCION);
        values.put(contracts.clienterEntry.Cciudad,cMACIUDAD);
        values.put(contracts.clienterEntry.Ctipo,cMATIPO);
        values.put(contracts.clienterEntry.Ccanal,cMACANAL);
        values.put(contracts.clienterEntry.Clatitud,cMALATITUD);
        values.put(contracts.clienterEntry.Clongitud,cMALONGITUD);
        return  values;
    }
    public cliente(Cursor cursor){
        cMAId=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cid));
        cMACODIGO = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Ccodigo));
        cMANOMBRE = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cnombre));
        cMADIRECCION= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cdireccion));
        cMACIUDAD= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cciudad));
        cMACANAL= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Ccanal));
        cMALONGITUD=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Clongitud));
        cMALATITUD = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Clatitud));
    }
    public String getcMAId() {
        return cMAId;
    }

    public String getcMACODIGO() {
        return cMACODIGO;
    }

    public String getcMANOMBRE() {
        return cMANOMBRE;
    }

    public String getcMADIRECCION() {
        return cMADIRECCION;
    }

    public String getcMACIUDAD() {
        return cMACIUDAD;
    }

    public String getcMATIPO() {
        return cMATIPO;
    }

    public String getcMACANAL() {
        return cMACANAL;
    }

    public String getcMALATITUD() {
        return cMALATITUD;
    }

    public String getcMALONGITUD() {
        return cMALONGITUD;
    }

}
```

Almaceno y obtengo información de sqlite.

Comment: revisa esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11881/crear-un-recyclerview-con-cursoradapter-para-base-de-datos-con-m%C3%BAltiples-tablas

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes vacía tus datos del cursor a un `ArrayList<>` de objetos que necesitas manejar.

Luego implementar un adapater para el recyclerview, en este caso te paso un adapter que implemento con CardView.

En este adapter le estoy pasando unos Listener a los CardView para agregarle la funcionalidad de Click y LongClick a cada CardView.

```
public class FichasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FichasAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Ficha> fichas;
    private int layout;
    private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    private OnItemLongClickListener longClickListener;

    public FichasAdapter(ArrayList<Ficha> fichas, int layout, OnItemClickListener listener, OnItemLongClickListener longClickListener) {
        this.fichas = fichas;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.itemClickListener = listener;
        this.longClickListener = longClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Inflamos el layout y lo pasamos al constructor del ViewHolder
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FichasAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Se llama al metodo Bind del ViewHolder donde pasamos el obejeto a procesar y el Listener
        holder.bind(fichas.get(position),itemClickListener,longClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fichas.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //Elementos de la UI CardView a llenar
        private TextView tvFicha,tvFichaPorcentaje;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            tvFicha = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ficha);
            tvFichaPorcentaje = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fichaPorcentaje);;
        }

        public void bind(final Ficha ficha,
                         final OnItemClickListener listener,
                         final OnItemLongClickListener longClickListener){
            //Procesamos los datos a renderizar
            tvFicha.setText(ficha.getFicha());
            tvFichaPorcentaje.setText(ficha.getPorcentaje().toString());
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(ficha, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    longClickListener.onItemLongClick(ficha,getAdapterPosition());
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public  interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(Ficha ficha, int position);
    }
    public  interface OnItemLongClickListener{
        void onItemLongClick(Ficha ficha, int position);
    }
}
```

Luego en tu Actividad o fragment debes Asignar tu adapter a tu recyclerview de esta forma:

```
public class FichasFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<Ficha> fichas= new ArrayList<Ficha>();
    private FichasAdapter mAdapterFichas;
    private LayoutManager layout;  
    public FichasFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fichas, container, false);       
        
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rcv_fichas);        

        layout = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        //Con este metedo Inicializar estoy lo unico que hago es cargar
        //mi ArrayList<Ficha> con objetos de tipo Ficha

            inicializarDatos();       

        mAdapterFichas = new FichasAdapter(fichas, R.layout.cardview_ficha, new FichasAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(Ficha etiqueta, int position) {
              //Accion que quieres que se ejecute al hacer click en cada elemento
            }
        }, new FichasAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(Ficha etiqueta, int position) {//accion al hacer LongClick en el elemento
                deleteFicha(position);
            }
        });
        //mAdapterFichas = new FichaAdapter_OLD(fichas);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterFichas);        

        return v;
    }
```

Espero te sirva de guía para implementar tu adapter, solo debes modificarlo a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un lista personalizada que es muy parecida al ListView pero que se le pueden agregar maas detalles.
primero debes crear un xml con los campos que quieres que se muestren en tu lista.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<!--  listrow  -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_row_image"
        android:layout_width="64dip"
        android:layout_height="64dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- titulo de la categoria -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_row_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="title"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" />
```

Segundo debes crear un adaptador personalizado que extienda de BaseAdapter el te indicara que sobre escribas sus metodos, y en su constructor le debes pasar el contexto y la lista de datos que quieres mostrar.

```
package com.example.desarrollo.pruebalist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// Declare Variables
Context context;
String[] productos;
int[] imagenes;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] productos, int[] imagenes) {
    this.context = context;
    this.productos = productos;
    this.imagenes = imagenes;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return productos.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageView imgImg;

    //http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_title);
    imgImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_image);

    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    txtTitle.setText(productos[position]);
    imgImg.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);
    return itemView;
}
public static String detalle(Context context, String[] productos, int pos){
    String detallep="";
    for (int i = 0; i <productos.length ; i++) {
         detallep = productos[pos];
    }
    return  detallep;

  }
}
```

Luego en tu clase principal debes setear al lsitview tu adptador

```
 package com.example.desarrollo.pruebalist;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListViewAdapter adapter;
Button btnsalir, btnPerfil;
String[] producto;


int[] imagenes = {
        R.drawable.iphone,
        R.drawable.ipad,
        R.drawable.celular,
        R.drawable.laptop,
        R.drawable.desktop,
        R.drawable.chomecast,
        R.drawable.dvd,
        R.drawable.software,
        R.drawable.hardware,
        R.drawable.monitor,
        R.drawable.mouse,
        R.drawable.teclado,
        R.drawable.bluetooh,
        R.drawable.disco,
        R.drawable.ddr
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    producto = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.producto);
    btnPerfil = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPefil);
    btnsalir= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSalir);
    final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, producto, imagenes);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);


    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetalleActivity.class);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"posicion"+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            d.putExtra("posicion",i);
            startActivity(d);
            finish();
        }
    });

    lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetalleActivity.class);
           startActivity(d);
           return true;
        }
    });

    btnsalir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            finish();
        }
    });

    btnPerfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PerfilActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    });

 }

}
```

Aqui te dejo el proyecto completo en github https://github.com/igmer/List_Adapter_Custom